# Access object in another class

Tags: python, class, object

I'm creating a bar program, with bartenders, waiters and guests. I've got the mainframe setup but I also want to add so that whenever a bartender makes a drink it removes specific cl's of ingredients from the stock. However I have a hard time figuring out how to access thoose values.

Here is (some) of my code:

```
class Liquor(Item):
    #List of the objects name found in the class
    instances = []

    #Every liquor has a name, how much stock is left, brand, cl_price, percentage of alcohol
    def __init__(self, name, stock, brand, cl_price, percentage) -> None:
        super().__init__(stock, name)
        self.cl_price = cl_price
        self.percentage = percentage
        self.brand = brand

        #Adds all instances of the class to a list
        self.__class__.instances.append(name)

    #Returns the names of the instances found in the class
    def liquor_list():
        return '\n'.join(Liquor.instances)

#Liquor Creation
Vodka = Liquor('Vodka', 79, 'Absolut', '35 kr', '37.5%')
Mezcal = Liquor('Mezcal', 56, 'Corte Vetusto', '55 kr', '45%')
Whiskey = Liquor('Ardbeg', 94, 'Ardbeg', '50 kr', '46%',)
Rum = Liquor('Rum', 109, 'Havana Club', '25 kr', '37.5%')
Baileys = Liquor('Baileys', 43, 'Baileys', '20 kr', '17%')
```

This one is for the "Human" classes

```
import Bar_Back
import random

#Main class Person
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

#Subclass Guest
class Guest(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, drinks) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.drinks = drinks
    
    #Prints the current Liquor Menu
    def ask_for_menu(self):
        print(f'The current liquor menu is \n{Bar_Back.Liquor.liquor_list()}')
    
    #The guests places an order which is stored in the waiter order list
    def place_order(self, order, this_waiter):
        this_waiter.add_order(order)

#Subclass Waiter
class Waiter(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, order_list = []) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.order_list = order_list

    #Adds an order to a list which is stored
    def add_order(self, order):
        self.order_list.append(order)
        print(f'Added {order} to the order list: {self.order_list}')
    
    #Remove an order, once it's complete by the bartender
    def remove_order(self, complete_drink):
        self.order_list.remove(complete_drink)
        print(f'Drink {complete_drink} is complete!')
    
    #Print out the order_list
    def tell_bartender(self):
        print(f'Could you please make the following: {self.order_list}')

    #Prints a 'random' greeting phrase
    def welcome(self):
        greeting_phrases = ['Welcome', 'How are you today?', 'Hello!', 'Hey!']
        print(greeting_phrases[random.randint(0,3)])
    
    def serve(self, drink):
        print(f'Here is your {drink}. Hope it tastes well!')
    

#Subclass Bartender
class Bartender(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, speciality) -> None:
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.speciality = speciality
    
    #Makes a specific drink, and removes that drink from the waiters order list using
    def make_drink(self, drink, this_waiter):
        this_waiter.remove_order(drink)
        this_waiter.serve(drink)
    
    #Buys more of a Liquor
    def buy_more(self, liquor):
        Bar_Back.liquor.stock += 100
        print(f'New stock of {Bar_Back.Liquor.name} is {Bar_Back.Liquor.stock}')
```

so in the bartender method `make_drink` I want it to reduce the stock of a specific liquor (the stock amount is listed in program `Bar_Back` and is seen in the code above. How do I access this and change the value of the stock of I.E Vodka from `79 cl` to `74 cl`.

Hope I managed to formulate my question well, if you have any questions or concerns feel free to comment and I will try to answer anything that wasnt made clear.

Comment: You would need to store the stock amount in each `Liquor` object, and reduce it when a drink is made.  Currently, you're just throwing away the value of that parameter.

Comment: Why don't you do it in the same way as you increase the stock in `buy_more`?

Comment: the buy_more method isn't working yet, my bad forget to edit it out, but yes that is the same dilemma.